# Applying for masters again, will the application be evaluated on the basis of undergraduate/Bachelors or the most recent postgraduate grades

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, application, undergraduate, grades

Applying for masters but have a previous uncompleted masters on my profile. Will that grades from that masters be factored in when the admission committee evaluates my application. What if i have very good GPA is Bachelors, but got bad grades in Masters due to some circumstances.

Comment: Your entire record is usually considered.

Comment: This is going to depend on the institution you apply to.

Answer (score 2):

The admission committee will see your entire record.  It is up to them to decide how to consider and weigh the various parts of it - different people will feel differently about this, and there is no way to know what the sense of the committee as a whole will be.

If you had special circumstances that affected your grades, you should address them in your statement of purpose or cover letter.

See also:

[How do you get a bad transcript past Ph.D. admissions?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/324/how-do-you-get-a-bad-transcript-past-ph-d-admissions)

[Should I mention a "math depression" I went through in my letter of motivation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14498/should-i-mention-a-math-depression-i-went-through-in-my-letter-of-motivation)

[Applying for PhD after a poor master's](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1523/applying-for-phd-after-a-poor-masters)