# Will my UGPA keep my application from even being looked at, despite having turned things around?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gpa

I'm an international student who recently applied to CS Ph.D. programs in the US and this thought's been eating me up. My undergrad background isn't actually in CS. I was originally a literature major and did a CS double major. I wasn't familiar with anything, so my GPA tanked. It's around 3.1-3.2/4.0. If you take the CS-only courses, then it's actually around 2.95/4.0.

I'm a master's student right now, and I've managed to maintain a GPA of around 3.8-3.9/4.0. Aside from my UGPA I think my application isn't _that_ bad - good GRE/TOEFL scores, publications as a coauthor, and good LoR's. However, I've been consistently hearing that the undergrad GPA is "what matters most" and that it may keep me from having a person even reading my application. I personally think that's asinine and doesn't make any sense, but I suppose I'm not in a position to be voicing my opinion on that. I'm just wondering what the point of working hard to turn things around is if someone's application won't even be looked at.

The anxiety's been even worse because I've been hearing of people who chose the same POI's as me getting interviews, and I  haven't been hearing anything yet. I was hoping that people more knowledgeable than I am may be able to provide their two cents. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, most of the answers/questions of that type seem to be speaking under the assumption that people actually look at your entire application. My concern is more about the things I hear regarding "undergrad GPA filtering."

Comment: Also related: [1](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/73043/if-i-have-a-low-gpa-in-undergrad-and-want-to-get-into-top-phd-programs-should) and [2](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/324/how-do-you-get-a-bad-transcript-past-ph-d-admissions)

Comment: If you apply someplace that filters based on undergrad grades and you miss their cut, nothing you can do. If they are highly selective then there are surely applicants who have better masters grades than you too, and also great GREs and publication history anyways. If not, then all the other answers at that linked question apply.

Comment: You might be better off contacting the prospective departments on this matter, rather than asking on Stack Exchange.  They will likely know better than random people on Stack Exchange.