# What can I do in my last semester to improve my chances of admission to physics PhD with a poor GPA?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, physics

I am transitioning from EE to Physics in MS program. I am taking courses required for my research. Also, I am taking courses that will help me in finding employment after MS. Due to this act of balance, and doing research, my overall GPA has plummetted to 3.3 ( At the moment my major GPA is also same). I have one more semester to go. What should I do to improve my chance to boost my GPA so that I can apply to top PhD programs in Physics? I am doing MS theses.

Comment: Unfortunately, we strangers on the internet are unable to determine which of two reasonable choices is the best fit for your personal circumstances, capabilities, and desires.  If there are questions about the larger system that would give you the information that can help you make your decision, however, those are more likely to be on topic.

Comment: Please also note that supplying more information will not change the reason that your questions are being closed: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/82092/22733

Comment: Hi, Thanks! Do we have any active faculty on stackexchange? since they have already walked  this path, they may give some advice.

Comment: There are lots of active faculty on Academia.SE. They are voting to close your questions because you are not following the guidelines in [the help center](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Please particularly read the section on "Can I ask questions about my specific situation?"

Comment: Ok! Got it. I will try to generalize this question. Maybe in a sentence or two.

Comment: See [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in the US, particularly for weak or borderline students?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly), and [How do you get a bad transcript past Ph.D. admissions?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/324/how-do-you-get-a-bad-transcript-past-ph-d-admissions)