# How to Get Into European Grad School in Journalism with a Low GPA

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, europe, gpa, humanities

I'm wondering if someone can advise.  I have a BA in Literature and a pretty low GPA under 3.0 from 2008.  I've worked in varied industries, teaching (preschool, ESL) and IT (Data Analysis).  I want to change careers and go into journalism.  I am planning to take some online courses and submit web content/start a blog, but a portfolio is far in the future. I am looking to get a master in journalism in Europe.  The schools I'm focused on are primarily in Germany (HMKW Berlin, Cologne) and CZ.  Also considering applying to France or Belgium.  I'm concerned that I won't get in due to my grades and will need to cast a wide net. 
 Is there any way to make my application more attractive to prospective schools? How do I try to make a good impression with school heads on first contact?

Comment: Europe is not a uniform block and entrance requirements are pretty different from country to country. GPA is a US thing, each university in Europe may have their own grade translation conventions, and in many cases the GPA may be irrelevant or not particularly relevant. Moreover, what do you mean by grad school, master or PhD? In Europe, many universities require first a master's degree to enter a PhD programme.

Comment: I am looking to get a master (preferrably 2 years).  I was concentrating on schools in Germany and CZ, but wanted to cast a wider net (France, Belgium, Italy) because I'm worried I won't get in anywhere.  In the US, bad grades force you to rely on contacts/internships/letters/GREs I'm not sure how it works here.

Comment: Not my field or location, but do you need a masters to get in the door in journalism? Or can you get some experience first and then use that to help? It might also make it clear whether this is a good move or not.

Comment: Buffy- it helps for contacts and to learn the craft properly, also employers do look at that and I have no experience.  Experience is needed to get in the door and it's pretty competitive.  I tend to want more structured instruction. I picked up some udemy/edX courses in the meantime. I worked in IT (SAS/SQL) previously so I don't have relevant experience.

Comment: Related: [How do you get a bad transcript past Ph.D. admissions?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/324/how-do-you-get-a-bad-transcript-past-ph-d-admissions)

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I will try to answer more generally, hence some of the examples will not apply. I have no experience in journalism.

Over the years, for graduate school applications in hard sciences, prior research experience became almost a requirement at the higher level of applicants. These usually present itself as a project done before the application and can add tremendous value to an application. Hard sciences also have serious limitations for undergraduate approach-ability to research. You may need equipment, prior knowledge and an understanding of the state of affairs in your field. Thus, these projects often occur under some form of supervision from a superior researcher / teacher.

In disciplines such as journalism or photography. These prerequisites need not apply. One can get into serious journalistic effort independently, with very little financial need. I know the act of journalism is not the academic study of journalism. However, field experience surely would be valuable. You can also show your eager and edge. For example, all the university newspapers I know are official publications of the universities and therefore subject to a serious amount of censure or whitewashing. Even worse is, their bloodstream is the volunteer work of students on topics that do not actually matter. Literally, any of these students can start a webpage within an hour of learning html, do their independent journalism in issues that matter. Yet to see anyone actually doing it... I had seen a story of systematic sexual assaults by a member of staff in an University broken by the women studies society announced over twitter. I wonder how much sooner, and better we would understand the problem if there was an actual journalist people could talk to.

There are countless things you can do. Write a story. Find something that you are interested in and talk to the people. It is the age of internet. Okay, maybe I can't afford to go to Iran to report on the state of affairs but for example you can find online Iranians will to speak about a particular thing. You can do something local. You can ask how waitresses whose livelihood entirely depend on tips surviving during the pandemic in US. You can get a small tripod and a wireless microphone, record some interviews on your phone, edit it and present. You already are technically capable. Just do it.

For the application end however, it is better for you to demonstrate quality rather then quantity. Maybe start with smaller more frequent stuff and then focus into issues more in depth. Admission boards are less likely to read pages and pages of reports per applicant. But they can maybe read or watch a medium sized article you worked really hard on. Ideally display your academic understanding of journalism. Not only stating facts but commenting, putting in perspective etc. (or whatever it is that proper journalists do, I am not an expert).

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you start a blog, and then also maybe sign up for a journalism course. A lot of prestigious colleges offer extension courses that are accredited and you can learn about what you are trying to get into. It will help you decide if you really want to do journalism. I know that some schools have specific GPA requirements, but a lot say that they are not the required minimum. Look to see if they have certificate/test requirements and do well on the entrance essay. GPA isn't everything!